# Please help with the rank-1 matrix eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the eigenvector problem:
$Aw = \lambda B w$.

If the rank of A is at most 1 (assume B is the full rank matrix), then there is at most one eigenvector corresponding to the nonzero eigenvalue. Is that correct?

If so, what if the problem of $Bw = \lambda A w$? Does this still only has one eigenvector corresponding the nonzero eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is an invertible  matrix, $A w = \lambda B w$ is equivalent to
$B^{-1} A w = \lambda w$, i.e. $\lambda$ is an eigenvector of $B^{-1} A$, and $B^{-1} A$ has the same rank as $A$.  A matrix of rank $1$ can only have at most one nonzero eigenvalue, and the eigenvectors for this eigenvalue form a one-dimensional subspace (it's not correct to say "one eigenvector", because 
if $v$ is an eigenvector then so is $t v$ for any nonzero scalar $t$).

Comment: Thanks for the answering. Then what is the rank of $BA^{-1}$?

Comment: There is no $B A^{-1}$, because $A$ is not invertible (if this is in dimension $> 1$).